# Iterating a continuous or differentiable function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, limits, continuity, fixed-point-theorems

I would like to know whether the following statement or a weaker / similar version of it is true. Intuitively, it seems to me that it should be true but I'm unable to prove it. Does anyone know a theorem with a name that states something like the below? Thanks so much.

> Let $f: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ be a
> differentiable function defined on some interval $[a,b]$ and let
> $c \in [a,b]$ be such that
>
> - $f^n(c) \in [a,b]$ for all $n$, where $f^n$ denotes function iteration
> - for all $d \in [a,b]$ for which there exists an $m \ge 1$ with $f^{m}(d) = d$ we have $f(d) = d$
>
> Then $f^n(c)$ converges as $n$ converges to infinity.

Comment: I think for the second hypothesis you want to say instead: if $f^m(d) = d$ for $m \geq 2$, then $f(d) = d$. (i.e. there can be fixed points but any fixed point of an iterate is a fixed point of the original map.)

Comment: otherwise the putative limit $d$ of the $f^n(c)$ is a counterexample

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Thanks for pointing it out!